Babel french with TikZ not working inside beamer frame
I attempt to use the TikZ declare function feature in a french document.
I noticed there is a clash between french babel option and TikZ because it modifies the the semicolon interpretation. That's why I call \usetikzlibrary{babel} as suggested here, and the following code works as expected:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}                      
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Carre(\x)=\x*\x;}]
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [domain=-1:1] plot {Carre(\x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
   
\end{document}

The problem arises when I embed the code inside a frame environment:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}                      
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}  

\begin{frame}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \frametitle{Test}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Carre(\x)=\x*\x;}]
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [domain=-1:1] plot {Carre(\x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}%>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

\end{document}

I don't understand why it doesn't work any more. Any ideas? Thank you!

You can use the fragile frame option (note that \end{frame} must be on a line of its own without a comment after it)
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}                      
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}  

\begin{frame}[fragile]%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \frametitle{Test}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={Carre(\x)=\x*\x;}]
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [domain=-1:1] plot {Carre(\x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



@thisirs' suggestion founded here seems to work (and doesn't need TikZ babel library any more):
\usepackage[babel=true, kerning=true]{microtype}

I don't know if some secondary effects have to be encountered.
